# Filter table data into an Array with criteria from a column within that table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, criteria

I am trying to filter table data into an array with criteria from a separate column within that table.

I can achieve this on a worksheet with a simple formula which creates a spilled array.

```
=FILTER(tblMain[Name],tblMain[At Work]=1)
```

I get errors with this code:

```vb
Sub myArraySub()
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray1 As Variant
Dim myArray2 As Variant
Dim myArray3 As Variant

'Set path for Table variable
    Set myTable = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("tblMain")
'Create Array
    myArray1 = Application.Transpose(myTable.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.Value)
    myArray2 = Application.Transpose(myTable.ListColumns("At Work").DataBodyRange.Value)
    myArray3 = Application.Filter(myArray1, myArray2 = 1)
End Sub
```

I will ultimately use the array to test other tables if the Name appears in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this with this approach, mainly because in VBA you can't compare an array directly to a single value and return an array.

What you could do is use Evaluate with the formula you already have.

```vb
Sub myArraySub()
Dim myArray1 As Variant

    myArray1 = Evaluate("=FILTER(tblMain[Name],tblMain[At Work]=1)")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @norie. That worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't can't use very creative answer you got from @Norie in this thread, your question was also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995761/how-do-i-copy-a-filtered-range-into-an-array-excel-vba) extensively. But reading through all the solutions there I wondered whether they were worth the effort. So, here is a more plodding way of achieving the same result. It may well be your best bet if the number of rows in your table isn't very large.

```
Function MyArray() As Variant
    
    Dim Fun         As Variant          ' function return array
    Dim Arr         As Variant          ' working copy of entire table
    Dim Rs          As Long             ' loop counter: Arr (Source) rows
    Dim Rt          As Long             ' loop counter: Fun (Target) rows
    Dim C           As Long             ' loop counter: columns
    
    Arr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("tblMain").DataBodyRange.Value
    ReDim Fun(1 To UBound(Arr, 2), 1 To UBound(Arr))
    For Rs = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If Arr(Rs, 2) = 1 Then
            Rt = Rt + 1
            For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Fun(C, Rt) = Arr(Rs, C)
            Next C
        End If
    Next Rs
    
    ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To UBound(Fun), 1 To Rt)
    MyArray = Application.Transpose(Fun)
End Function
```

Use the little procedure below for testing.

```
Sub Test_MyArray()

    Dim Arr     As Variant
    Dim R       As Long
    Dim C       As Long
    
    Arr = MyArray
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            Debug.Print Arr(R, C),
        Next C
        Debug.Print
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. The solution provided by @norie worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve :)